# How does a two-tensor transform under an infinitesimal shift?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, covariance

This is a follow-up to this question I posted yesterday: [How does a vector field transform under an infinitesimal coordinate transformation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310178/)

If I have an infinitesimal coordinate shift of the form $x^{\mu} \to x^{\mu} + v^{\mu}(x)$, The the vector field $A^{\mu}(x)$ will transform like:
$$
A^{\mu}(x) \to A^{\mu}(x) + \mathcal{L}_{v}(A^{\mu})(x)
$$
where $\mathcal{L}_{v}(A^{\mu}) = v^{\nu} \partial_{\nu}A^{\mu} - A^{\nu} \partial_{\nu} v^{\mu}$ is the Lie derivative of $A$ wrt $v$.

If I build a field strength tensor $F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu} A^{\mu}$, is it true that this tensor transforms to the following object?
$$
\to \partial^{\mu} \left( A^{\nu} + v^{\rho} \partial_{\rho}A^{\nu} - A^{\rho} \partial_{\rho} v^{\nu} \right) - \partial^{\nu} \left( A^{\mu} + v^{\rho} \partial_{\rho}A^{\mu} - A^{\rho} \partial_{\rho} v^{\mu} \right)
$$

I think this is the case, but I'd like to confirm this. It's pretty messy.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

In components, the Lie derivative of a doubly contravariant tensor such as $F^{\mu\nu}$ is given by 
$$
({\mathcal L}_X F)^{\mu \nu}= X^\lambda  \partial_\lambda F^{\mu\nu}- F^{\lambda\nu} \partial_\lambda X^\mu - F^{\mu\lambda}\partial_\lambda X^{\nu}.
$$
For doubly covariant tensor we have
$$
({\mathcal L}_X g)_{\mu \nu}= X^\lambda  \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}+ g_{\lambda\nu} \partial_\mu X^\lambda+g_{\mu\lambda}\partial_\nu X^{\lambda}.
$$
The genral pattern should now be clear.